# CPU Fan really annoying

Tags: hardware, cpu, fan, fancontrol

Nn a Dell Inspiron the CPU Fan is too loud. It is not running constantly, but it changes from slow to really fast every minute. It's really annoying and hardly possible to work on this machine.

Is it possible to limit the range the fan is using?

`pwmcontrol` says:

```
There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed
```

Answer (score 0):

Install lm-sensors and try again.  You can install lm-sensors with software center or in a bash terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install lm-sensors
```

Next try installing and using the i8kutils "Utilities for Dell Inspiron and Latitude laptops"

Comment: this is the sensors output: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1264781/

Comment: It's an Inspiron Desktop, not Laptop.